# Heroku - Django - How to reduce cool down of keep alive

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have an API that creates a model object whenever an action is true.

Slight problem, everytime the API sends some data it creates a connection and these connections dont seem to cool down very quickly.

Connections seem to stay on for more than 60 minutes.

This results in getting the following error: `too many connections for role xxx`

As a result, I implemented the following code in my **prod.py**:

```
from .base import *
from decouple import config
import django_on_heroku 
# Heroku Settings
django_on_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)

# Adjust database settings
import dj_database_url

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=450, ssl_require=True)
```

This was implemnted following Heroku's guidlines : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections

What I was hoping to achieve here was to have connections lasting a maximum of 45 seconds. (users dont need to spend more than 20 seconds on the site to get what they need).

I seem to be missing something. Would you be able to shed some lights?

Is there a better practice to ensure connections do not reach their limit?

Edit: worth mentioning, I am on the Basic plan. Planning to move to Standard0 when ready for production. I am assuming the plan shouldnt affect the ability to define keep alives.

Comment: Per [conn_max_age](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-CONN_MAX_AGE) this `conn_max_age=450` means the age in seconds so it would be 7.5 minutes.

Comment: I did notice that after I posted this. I thought the value was in millisecondes. I moved it back to 45, but still the connections are staying on for a lot longer than 40 minutes. (thanks for picking this up though!)

Comment: 1) 450/1000 = 0.45 secs. 2) [Persistent connection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#persistent-database-connections): *Django opens a connection to the database when it first makes a database query. It keeps this connection open and reuses it in subsequent requests. Django closes the connection once it exceeds the maximum age defined by CONN_MAX_AGE or when it isn’t usable any longer.*. So if new requests are happening with in the 45 secs the connection will stay open.

Comment: Do you really need connection pooling? How many concurrent connections do you expect? Django's persistent connection handling is very simplistic and causes more issues than it solves. Set it to `conn_max_age=0` if you don't really need it.

Comment: @Selcuk You cannot get good performance with a database application unless you use connection pooling.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What is the metric for "good performance"? That depends on the usage pattern, no? If the next request usually comes after 1 minute there is no point keeping the connection open for 45 seconds. Also Django doesn't have real connection pooling, you can't limit the total number of connections.

Comment: @Selcuk Right, if you don't need good performance, and if you can afford to waste server resources, my point is irrelevant.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That's not what I wrote, but feel free to interpret it any way you want.

Comment: @Selcuk Sorry if I misunderstood. But it is much cheaper to keep an idle connection open for a minute than to establish a new database connection every minute.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe All good. You are of course technically correct. My point was Django doesn't do proper pooling as you can't set an upper limit and may quickly run out of connections (as can be seen from the `too many connections` error). It is better to disable it altogether if your traffic doesn't justify it. Otherwise I was going to suggest using something like pgbouncer.

Comment: @Selcuk If that's the case, I would say the only good solution is to steer clear of Django.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Connection pooling is not the responsibility of an application development framework. The best practice is to use the `conn_max_age` in tandem with a connection pool, such as [pgbouncer](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pgbouncer-types-of-postgresql-connection-pooling/). In real world people don't change their tech stack just because they need to complement it with a third party library.

Comment: @Selcuk Well, people have always made bad software choices, that's life. There are people who willingly use Microsoft Teams or Odoo.